# Find out the cause for continous disk io on raspberry pi on arch

Tags: arch-linux, mysql, disk-usage, arm, sd-card

I have a raspberry pi (3B+) that's continously writing/reading from the SD card with no obvious reason (I see the green LED continously flashing). How do I troubleshoot and resolve this? I don't want it to eat up all the IO cycles on my SD card.

My RasPi is a headless system, running ArchARM with Nextcloud (with external RAID mirror on two USB thumb drives) and Apache, nothing too crazy and the disk access keeps happening even when I unplug the Ethernet cable (no wifi or bluetooth connections).
I've moved `/tmp` and `/var/log` to ramdisk already:

```
$ mount | grep tmpfs
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=423248k,nr_inodes=105812,mode=755)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noatime,size=102400k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /var/log type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noatime,size=102400k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/1001 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=92160k,mode=700,uid=1001,gid=985)
```

I installed `iotop` and the first line almost constantly reads `[jbd2/mmcblk0p2-]` with `mysqld` being at the second position (sometimes it hops in fron of `[jbd2/mmcblk0p2-]`, too). What is keeping the disk so busy? (and what is `jbd2`?)
I've got the following partition setup:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1 119.2G  0 disk  
`-sda1        8:1    1 114.6G  0 part  
  `-md0       9:0    0 114.5G  0 raid1 /mnt/usb
sdb           8:16   1 114.6G  0 disk  
`-sdb1        8:17   1 114.6G  0 part  
  `-md0       9:0    0 114.5G  0 raid1 /mnt/usb
mmcblk0     179:0    0 119.3G  0 disk  
|-mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   121M  0 part  /boot
`-mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 119.1G  0 part  /
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out, that the writes were caused by my zsh shell with help of the link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/acmesystems/OR5ZaQPS3yw I changed the default shell back to bash but to my surprise, there was still regular disk access (as monitored by looking at the LED), `iotop` tellme this time that something called `[kworker/2:0-events_freezable]` is causing the disk access - so I'm on the search to finf out more about that now